# Formation of a pH gradient using carrier ampholites

Tags: biochemistry, analytical-chemistry

In a technique called isoelectric focusing, the crucial part is the formation of a pH gradient using carrier ampholytes. What is the exact principle by which the gradient is formed? How do the ampholytes "know" exactly where to migrate, since they are the only protonizable chemical species in the solution?